Google SQL - Return the most frequent string dependent on 2 columns
I need to find the most frequent text value in a table but I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around applying the solutions I have found to my dataset.
My table is structured as follows:



Column A
Column B




Val A
Val a


Val A
Val b


Val A
Val a


Val B
Val a


Val B
Val b


Val B
Val b



I have created gotten the basic concept of calculating mode using count and max functions with CTEs but I really can't figure out how to return the table I need.
What I am expecting is a table like:



Column A
Column B




Val A
Val a


Val B
Val b



Val a is the most frequent for Val A and b for B.
There are hundreds of unique values in Col A and I'm trying to solve this so that I can then return the 2nd most frequent value in Col B if the most frequent is null.
Thanks for any guidance!
WITH counts AS(
  SELECT
  ColA,
  COUNT(ColB) AS ColB_count
  FROM table
  GROUP BY ColA
)

SELECT ColA, ColB_count
FROM counts
WHERE ColB_count = (
  SELECT MAX(ColB_count)
  FROM counts
);


You need to clarify what you want. It is not clear how you define "the most frequent string" when  you have two columns of strings. The most frequent in either column, in both, in one or the other, ... or ? What?

Ah thank you for the call out.
I am looking to return the most frequent string in Col B for each unique value in Col A.
My poorly written SQL is currently returning a single row (adding to the original question)

What's the expected result if there are two Column B values having the same most frequency? I.e. add the row (Val B, Val a) to your sample data.

Thankfully there is not an issue to return either value in Column B if there is a tie in frequency.

I'd say this is what you are trying to do with your attempted sql. Loosely speaking, you need the counts, and then you need the max counts, and then you need to put these two back together to match the max count with the value (from ColB) that it goes with. But be sure to test with ties and with nulls (if applicable) to ensure you understand how these cases will behave.
with cte1 as (
    select 
        ColA,
        ColB,
        count(ColB) as CountOfColB
    from Table
    group by
        ColA,
        ColB
),
cte2 as (
    select
        ColA,
        Max(CountOfColB) as total
    from cte1
    group by ColA
)
select 
    cte1.ColA,
    cte1.ColB
    --,cte1.CountOfColB
from 
    cte1
    inner join cte2
    on cte1.ColA = cte2.ColA
    and cte1.CountOfColB = cte2.total
order by 
    cte1.ColA,
    cte1.ColB

This is another approach using a window function with rank in the second cte (again, check your results when/if you have ties or nulls to be sure you are handling these as desired):
with cte1 as (
    select 
        ColA,
        ColB,
        count(ColB) as CountOfColB
    from Table
    group by
        ColA,
        ColB
),
cte2 as (
    select
        ColA,
        ColB,
        rank() over (partition by ColA order by CountOfColB) as RankedValue
    from cte1
)
select 
    cte2.ColA,
    cte2.ColB
from 
    cte2
where cte2.RankedValue = 1
order by 
    cte2.ColA,
    cte2.ColB


Thank you! This provided the results I needed and informed me that I need to study inner joins.
I spent last night implementing and testing. Thankfully ties are a non issue for my use case.
Ideally I would like to find a way to handle the case when NULL is the most frequent value and return the 2nd most frequent value. After trying some case statements though I think I'll work with what you helped me produce for now.

You can count pairs (colA,colB) by grouping. Null values excluded before grouping.
Then take first row from partition ordered by count desc (rn=1).
See example
with myTable as(
  select 1 colA,20 colB
  union all
  select 1 colA,30 colB
  union all
  select 1 colA,20 colB
  union all
  select 1 colA,20 colB
  union all
  select 1 colA,null colB
  union all
  select 1 colA,null colB
  union all
  select 1 colA,null colB
)
select *
from(
select colA,colB,count(*) cnt
   ,row_number()over(partition by colA order by count(*) desc)rn
from myTable
where colB is not null
group by colA,colB
)t
where rn=1

Case when 2 or more colB have same frequency, order is undefined, we will take any suitable one.
You can add some condition to order by clause of window function.
   ,row_number()over(partition by colA order by count(*) desc,colB)rn




colA
colB
cnt
rn




1
20
3
1



Update1.
For case where only one row for (colA,colB) and colB is null and you whant leave this row (not null's first asc)
select *
from(
select colA,colB,count(*) cnt
   ,row_number()
      over(partition by colA 
           order by case when colB is not null then 0 else 1 end,count(*) desc)rn
from myTable
group by colA,colB
)t
where rn=1


I was able to test this partially - one issue I run into with my data is that certain values in ColA consist of a single entry which is null in ColB.
If I exclude nulls in ColB I lose the entire row.
Annoyingly I would need to include some sort of logic after sorting to check if row 1 is null return row 2 unless there is no row 2.
